# Bash sed replace text with file content

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I would like to replace string with file.txt content.

```
mtn="John"
fs=`cat file.txt`
lgtxt=`cat large_text.txt`

stxt1=`echo $lgtxt | sed "s/zzzz/$mtn/g"`
stxt2=`echo $stxt1 | sed "s/pppp/$fs/g"`
```

It replace 'zzzz' with value of 'mnt' but doesn't 'pppp'.
File file.txt contain list of names eg: 
Tom jones
Ted Baker
Linda Evans
in separate lines.
I want to place them in file large_text.txt in separate lines like they are in oryginal file and separated by commas.

Comment: `m4(1)` is your friend.

Comment: Does pppp occur only once on a separate line? In that case we can look for another solution splitting the lgtxt by the pppp line. Or does pppp occur on some lines `if [ "${line}" = "pppp" ]; then ...`

Comment: No it occur within sentence and not only once.

Comment: SHow some sample input and expected output so we don't have to guess.

Comment: cat file.txt
`code`
Tom Jones
Ted Baker
Linda Evans

cat large_file.txt
This is the list of our students pppp.
pppp are students of our class.

Expected output:
This is the list of our students Tom jones Ted Baker Linda Evans.
Tom jones Ted Baker Linda Evans are students of our class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want to use a variable for the substitution (because it may well contain newlines, for example).  I'm assuming that it's GNU sed given it's [linux](/questions/tagged/linux).  In which case, see whether GNU sed's `r` command could help you:

> ```
> `r FILENAME'
>      As a GNU extension, this command accepts two addresses.
>
>      Queue the contents of FILENAME to be read and inserted into the
>      output stream at the end of the current cycle, or when the next
>      input line is read.  Note that if FILENAME cannot be read, it is
>      treated as if it were an empty file, without any error indication.
>
>      As a GNU `sed' extension, the special value `/dev/stdin' is
>      supported for the file name, which reads the contents of the
>      standard input.
> ```

If `pppp` is on a line of its own, you could go with something like

```
/pppp/{
r file.txt
d
}
```

or, alternatively, the `s` command with `e` modifier:

> ```
> `e'
>      This command allows one to pipe input from a shell command into
>      pattern space.  If a substitution was made, the command that is
>      found in pattern space is executed and pattern space is replaced
>      with its output.  A trailing newline is suppressed; results are
>      undefined if the command to be executed contains a NUL character.
>      This is a GNU `sed' extension.
> ```

This would look something like

```
s/pppp/cat file.txt/e
```

and is what you'll need if `pppp` is mid-line.  Also, if you need to do further processing on `file.txt`, you could replace `cat` with whatever you need (though you need to be careful about quoting `/` and `\`).

A final option is to consider Perl, which will accept something very similar to your shell commands.

Comment: `code` sed -i '/pppp/r file.txt' large_text.txt `code` nearly solved the problem ;-) . to get perfect result i need to delete 'pppp' after replacing.

What about same situation but replaced text need to be separated by commas?

Comment: @Marcin: I've edited to address your followup comment.