# replace the matched text with the contents of another file using sed inside a shell script

Tags: shell, awk, sed, makefile

I have a Makefiel which call a shell script. Inside that shell script I have the following sed command:

```
sed -e '/.section\t.text/{' -e 'r anotherfile.s' -e  'd' -e '}' input.s > output.s
```

which does not work.
while it works fine when I run this into terminal directly.
I want to search a line ".section   .text" in a file and replace it with another file.
What is wrong here?

## input.s

```
    .section    .data
    .addressing Word
_A: 
    .data.32    0
    .section    .text
    .addressing Word

_main:  
    LW  %GPR27, _C(%GPR0)
    NOP
```

## anotherfile.s

```
    .addr_space 32  ; address space is 2^32
    .addressing Byte    ; byte addressing          (default)
    .bits_per_byte  8   ; 1 byte consists of 8 bit (default)
    .endian     Big ; Big endian (default)

    .section    .text
    .org 0x00000000
```

## output.s (should be like this)

```
    .section    .data
    .addressing Word
_A: 
    .data.32    0
    .addr_space 32  ; address space is 2^32
    .addressing Byte    ; byte addressing          (default)
    .bits_per_byte  8   ; 1 byte consists of 8 bit (default)
    .endian     Big ; Big endian (default)

    .section    .text
    .org 0x00000000
    .addressing Word

_main:  
    LW  %GPR27, _C(%GPR0)
    NOP
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash sed replace text with file content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056599/bash-sed-replace-text-with-file-content)

Comment: Dear @Cyrus the command mentioned above, when i use it in the terminal. but when i run this command inside a shell script the output.s is same as input.s

Comment: When asking questions, never just say something `does not work` - tell us in what way it does not work: wrong output, no output, error messages, core dumps, etc. Asking for help to fix code that just "does not work" is like taking your car to the mechanic and just telling the mechanic "it does not work" and expecting her to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed is for doing s/old/new,  **that is all**. That's not what you're doing so you shouldn't be using sed so rather than trying to debug something you shouldn't be doing anyway, just use awk:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { rep = (rep=="" ? "" : rep ORS) $0; next }
/\.section\t\.text/ { $0 = rep }
{ print }
' anotherfile.s input.s > output.s
```